# Localhost Wordpress slow

Tags: wordpress, localhost, vagrant

I'm developing a project in Wordpress. I have a virtual machine with vagrant running in localhost and my project lasts 10 min loading everytime. In a remote server it just lasts about 3 or 4 seconds.

By the way, I have other projects in localhost that they do not last that much.

Is there any problem with localhost and Wordpress?

Thanks.

Comment: I guess it is because of the vagrant. Take a look at this post: https://stefanwrobel.com/how-to-make-vagrant-performance-not-suck

I have some more questions to find probably other problems.
Do you use a local database? Or is it on another server? 
Are the other projects with a database? 
What is the version of wordpress, PHP?

Comment: The DB is on another server and it works fine. I'll try that guide. Thanks

Comment: Working with an external DB on localhost slows down the project. I have no solution for this, only know that this is a known issue. 

This and a combination of vagant, you will get a waiting time of 10 minutes.

"I thought that was because the connection of the external server is faster then your own (dsl-)-connection. So it takes more time to load all the information in the DB"

Comment: What about static and PHP pages, are they as slow as WordPress? e.g. try loading the readme.html file, and try adding a PHP file with `echo phpinfo();` in it.  Check the DNS on your Vagrant server is correctly configured, do you have the right name servers, how long does it take the server to perform a DNS lookup etc.  (by the way, is it literally 10 minutes?)

Comment: I have a 600 sec timeout and sometime it works, other it gives me a timeout error, so yeah, more than 10 min. I will try your solutions guys, thanks. By the way, I installed XAMPP instead of vagrant and now it is about 3 or 4 mins (still so so slow).

Comment: FIXED!! It was the remote DB. With a local DB it just takes about 5 seconds to load. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 3):

I've had the same problem on Linux. Nothing worked including disabling cgi, tuning databases, etc.

Here's what did work for me. Running Centos 7.3.
I have multiple vhosts running under Apache 2.4.
WP domain: mysite.org

In /etc/hosts 
127.0.0.1 mysite.org

This was slow as heck on a fast computer. I'd tried everything. Then I determined it was a problem was with WP resolving 'things.' WP uses locahost.

My IP address on my local network was 192.168.0.106. I then tried that.

Changed /etc/hosts
192.168.0.106 mysite.org

Now WP runs fast on my local test server.

Answer (score 1):

Here's what i figured out. 
I opened my Hosts file in windows and it had a lot of unnecessary entries. I removed all unnecessary ones and then checked, there's been an incredible difference. Localhost WP is working super fast.

** The entries were associated to 127.0.0.1

I guess the fewer items associated to 127.0.0.1, the faster the localhost server becomes.

** This was experienced under Xampp.

Answer (score 0):

I know is a quite old question, but I solved disabling Wordfence plugin